# URL change but page does not refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am using react router 4. I have two components 1- ShopLogin 2- Shopper. I am trying to redirect from ShopLogin component to Shopper component after button click.
Everything is working fine. URL is also changing after button click. I am able to see 'Hello' also. 
But the problem is i am able to see both component on browser after button click. component is not refreshing. not sure why it is happening. Below are my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export class ShopLogin extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
}
SignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.history.push('/shopper');

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.SignIn.bind(this)}>SignIn</button>
        </div>
    );
    }
   }

ShopLogin.contextTypes = {
router: PropTypes.object
}


export default ShopLogin;
```

My Index.js

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ShopLogin from './ShopLogin';

import Shopper from './Shopper';

import { HashRouter,Route } from 'react-router-dom';


 ReactDOM.render((

 <HashRouter>

  <div>

  <Route path="/" component={ShopLogin} />

  <Route path="/shopperlogin" component={ShopLogin} />

  <Route path="/shopper" component={Shopper} />

   </div>
 </HashRouter>
   ), document.getElementById('root'))
```

My Shopper.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export class Shopper extends Component {

 constructor(props) 
{

super(props);

   this.state = {
    };

}

 render() 
 {

return (
  <div>
 Hello   </div>
);
}
}


export default Shopper;
```

Comment: I think you should use a <Link /> component here, or am I missing something? What is different from its behavior than what you are trying to achieve?

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: how it is different from what i am doing on button click?

Comment: I guess this route <Route path="/" component={ShopLogin} /> is also true for "/shopper" url which you're pushing with the button. use "exact" like:
 <Route exact path="/" component={ShopLogin} />

Comment: @user1269009 Thank you very much!!! it worked... how you identify that?

Comment: "/part1/" matches with "/part1/part2/part3" url also, if not used with exact in my understanding. it's funny that I'm still experimenting with react and I got it right :D

Answer (score 2):

It will show multiple components since on the route `'/shopper'`. The Routes checks successfully to the ShopLogin Component with the path `'/'` and it checks successfully to the Shopper Component with the path `'/shopper'`.

I would create a parent Component e.g. Main that just presents the child components and define the routes like this

1. import IndexRoute from react-router

   ```
   import { HashRouter,Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';
   ```
2. resort your routes to

   ```
   <HashRouter>
       <Route path='/' component={Main}>
           <Route path='/shopper' component={Shopper} />
           <IndexRoute component={ShopLogin} />
       </Route>
   </HashRouter>
   ```
3. Create your parent component for ShopLogin and Shopper components

   ```
   class Main extends Component {
       render(){
           return (
               <div>
                   {this.props.children}
               </div>
           )
   }
   ```

Comment: It isnot working for me.. also it is giving warning that can not use route under route.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reorder your routes and use the **exact** attribute and wrap all the routes with a **Switch**.

```
<HashRouter>
     <div>
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={ShopLogin} />
          <Route exact path="/shopper" component={Shopper} />
          <Route path="/shopperlogin" component={ShopLogin} />
       </Switch>
      </div>
</HashRouter>
```